# Copying files to USB 3.0 external HDD connected to USB 3.0 hub with external power supply connected to USB 2.0 port hangs and stops with IO error

Tags: external-hard-drive, compatibility, usb-3

When I connect my external HDD to USB 3.0 hub with external power supply connected to USB 2.0 port copying any bigger file to that HDD will freeze and eventually stop with error message. The same disk works fine when connected directly to the same USB port. It happens on windows and linux (tested on windows 7 and debian). The HDD is backwards compatible with USB 2.0.

Since it was IO error I tested the disk for errors with HD Tune, no errors found. I also tried different USB ports with the same result. It also works fine when the hub is connected to USB 3.0 port.

To clarify what I mean by "copying hangs": there is no progress at all, cancelling doesn't work, and killing the copy process isn't possible (even on linux with SIGKILL as root)

Is it normal/expected incompatibility or is there something wrong with my computer/USB hub/external HDD? If it shouldn't happen, what can I do to figure out why it happens?

note: I have PC and a laptop, the PC has no USB 3.0 ports and very few working easly accessible USB 2.0 ports.

Comment: It could be a bandwidth issue in the USB hub. Double check that you're using the correct power adapter for the USB hub. If the PC is having issues with USB ports (not due to hardware faults) then try performing a disk cleanup and registry clean up.

Comment: 1. I use the original power supply for the hub. And it works fine when the hub is connected to 3.0 port 2. It happens on windows and linux, and works fine when the HDD is connected directly to USB port, so it  can't really be fault of the OS.